# OpenID authentication code all in JS?

Tags: javascript, openid

I need to add OpenID authentication to my application. Can I actually have whole code in JS (i mean sending messages to OP and stuff?) or do i have to use some other language to write OpenID server code in? I was looking for entirely JS solutions but I cannot find any.

Comment: Do you mean writing the entire OpenID authentication mechanism in client side Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not, but this is probably a really bad idea since you will be storing authentication tokens and all kinds of stuff in there you wouldn't want exposed.